# How can I match constructor types with Java reflection with Scala primitive types?

Tags: java, scala

Say I have this class:

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

I want to reflect on the class at runtime using the Java reflection (not Scala).  (This is because I'm working on a Dotty library, which has static, but not runtime reflection.)

I am able to know the types of my constructor arguments:  java.lang.String, and Scala.Int.
But when I reflect on Person:

```scala
classOf[Person].getConstructors.toList
// List(public com.mypkg.sub.Person(java.lang.String,int))
```

See that 'int' there?  That's causing me to fail to find the matching constructor.  Using Java reflection on a Class I can look for a Constructor if I know the types.  How do I ask for int?  Some posts elsewhere suggest using Integer.TYPE, but that resolves to Scala.Int for me.

How can I successfully call `clazz.getConstructor(???)`?

Comment: Runtime reflection is rarely recommended

Comment: `classOf[Person].getConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[Int])`

Comment: Runtime reflection is common, but why do you need to use Java reflection instead of Scala reflection? @insan-e 's answer can get that constructor. Even your answer can do it for you as well like `classOf[Person].getConstructors.toList.head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask for its ClassTag:

```
scala> implicitly[reflect.ClassTag[Int]].runtimeClass eq java.lang.Integer.TYPE                                                                     
val res3: Boolean = true
```